# How does "merge without branch" work?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging

In this [simple guide to git](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/), a merge is always performed on a branch:

```
git merge <branch>
```

In my new work environment, however, I encountered a practice in which developers pull from the master (i.e. not to their own branch) but when they push their changes (which they performed on their own master), they push it to a different "master" (actually a "personal branch"). Then, the CI system attempts to merge that "personal branch" with the master (remote repository).

I know this works, because the team has been working like this for years. But how does something like this works from the perspective of `git` itself? Is it in line with the intended git concepts?

Or does it violate some basic principle?

Comment: The cool thing about git is that there are basically no rules, and therefore no violations of them.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Every wonderful system can be bent to do things in a way not intended. I am trying to understand how git can merge a non-branch (i.e. master with master?)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you. I wish I can upvote the answer I accepted. I think I need a minimum of 15 reputation to be able to upvote.

Comment: Eh, I'm sure you'll get there soon enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know this works, because the team has been working like this for years. But how does something like this works from the perspective of git itself
>      ...
>
> Then, the CI system attempts to merge that "personal branch" with the master 
>   (remote repository).

If you don't specify branch git use the current branch as the "second" branch name for the merging, in git you can write as many branches as you want for the merge.

```
git merge A B C  ... N
```

git will select the appropriate merge strategies based upon the number of branches.

---

> In my new work environment, however, I encountered a practice in which developers `pull` from the master (i.e. not to their own branch) but when they `push` their changes (which they performed on their own master), they push it to a different "master" (actually a "personal branch").
>
> Then, the CI system attempts to merge that "personal branch" with the master (remote repository).

There is nothing wrong with this way. Git is like an **untrained** beast. You can "train" any way you like as long as you are good with it.

So if this way suit your IT/devops team there is no problem with it.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. It is what I needed to clarify things in my very basic experience with git.

Comment: Np, im here for any other question you might have.